# scala spark databricks joblog trying to figure out how to gracefully extract data in non standard format

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, logging, databricks

I am working to extract data from job log json emitted by azure databricks. One of the entries in the json contains something close to a dictionary, but not quite, and I can't figure out a graceful--inline--way of extracting this data. I am using scala and creating a structure in scala that reflects the hierarchical nature of the job log. There are three data elements that contain a string in this format, one example is:

```
"response": "{\\"statusCode\\":200}"
```

It would make a nice json structure, if not for the backslash escaping the quotation marks and the double quotes at the start and end of the string.

I did a lot of internet searching, but have not found the words to describe this string format so the searches yield tons of irrelevant results.

I tried some regex to pre-process this to look like a json structure, but it did not work. This is what I tried:

```
case class cls_logJSON(value:String)
var df2 = df.withColumn("value",regexp_replace(col("value"), "\\\\", "")).as[cls_logJSON]
    df2 = df.withColumn("value",regexp_replace(col("value"), " \"{", " {")).as[cls_logJSON]
    df2 = df.withColumn("value",regexp_replace(col("value"), "}\",", "},")).as[cls_logJSON]
```

This is not code I like to see, and I am hoping this string format is some sort of standard that can be accessed with the proper data type or some such. I extract data from the dataframe created by these json lines and can access other data using dot notation such as `properties.sourceIPAddress`, and of course, I can get this data as a string, but I am trying to avoid some sort of rbar loop on each row of the dataframe. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add what is the exact input format and output you are expecting? - it would make the question simple

Comment: Thanks for your follow up. I would like to see the json object list format so that the standard json parsing can treat it as a structure full of name value pairs: 

"response": {"statusCode":200}

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% where I would like to be, but I did find a way to extract this data into a dataframe. The data is, oddly in my opinion, formatted as a json object within an outer json object, and can be accessed as below. I would have liked to string or chain some of the processing together, but I could not figure out how to do that, so I have three steps to get the data I needed. Here is the code. The 'from_json' function is able to extract this oddly formatted column data:

```
val reqParamStruct = 
StructType(
StructField("runId",StringType,true) ::
StructField("idInJob",StringType,true) ::
StructField("jobId",StringType,true) ::
StructField("jobTerminalState",StringType,true) ::
StructField("notebookPath",StringType,true) ::
StructField("jobTriggerType",StringType,true) ::
StructField("jobTaskType",StringType,true) ::
StructField("jobClusterType",StringType,true) :: 
StructField("multitaskParentRunId",StringType,true) :: 
StructField("taskDependencyType",StringType,true) :: 
StructField("run_name",StringType,true) :: 
StructField("taskKey",StringType,true) :: 
Nil)

val respParamStruct = 
StructType(StructField("statusCode",StringType,true) :: 
StructField("result",StringType,true) :: Nil)

val identityStruct = 
StructType(StructField("email",StringType,true) :: 
StructField("subjectName",StringType,true) :: Nil)

val resultStruct = 
StructType(StructField("email",StringType,true) :: 
StructField("run_id",StringType,true) :: Nil)

val jobDf_2 = jobDf.select(
$"resourceId",
$"identity",
$"operationName",
$"time",
$"properties.response",
$"properties.logId",
from_json($"identity",identityStruct).as("reqId"),
from_json($"properties.requestParams",reqParamStruct).as("reqParm"),
from_json($"properties.response",respParamStruct).as("respParm")
)

val jobDf_3 = jobDf_2.select(
$"resourceId",
$"reqId.email",
$"operationName",
$"time",
$"logId",
expr("reqParm.runId as reqRunId"),
$"reqParm.runId",
$"reqParm.idInJob",
$"reqParm.jobId",
$"reqParm.notebookPath",
$"reqParm.jobTriggerType",
$"reqParm.jobTaskType",
$"reqParm.jobClusterType",
$"reqParm.multitaskParentRunId",
$"reqParm.taskDependencyType",
$"reqParm.run_name",
$"reqParm.taskKey",

from_json($"respParm.result",resultStruct).as("result")
)

val jobDf_4 = jobDf_3.select(
$"resourceId",
$"email",
$"operationName",
$"time",
$"logId",
$"reqRunId",
$"idInJob",
$"jobId",
$"notebookPath",
$"jobTriggerType",
$"jobTaskType",
$"jobClusterType",
$"multitaskParentRunId",
$"taskDependencyType",
$"taskKey",
$"run_name",
expr("result.run_id as respRunId")
)
jobDf_4.createOrReplaceTempView("v_logEntries")
```